# Can an SSRS report be aware of its filepath?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working on SSRS reports and I'm trying to dynamically change the SQL based on which folder a report is in.  The same report will be deployed into two folders but the SQL needs to be different based on the folder.  My thoughts is that if I can access the filepath of a report I can alter the SQL based on the filepath.  Is there any way to access the filepath within a report?

Comment: If the report is being deployed in two different places, why not just make two different reports?

Comment: It saves so instead of editing two files and deploying them separately, I can edit one file and deploy that one twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query parameter that is set to the Report Folder [&ReportFolder].

You can pick it by clicking the Function button and choosing it under Built-In Fields.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!